# I can select an image from the device but it wont upload on and due to that, I am unable to create a user

Tags: java, android, imageview

For my app to register a user all it fills needs to be filled. However when I select an image when clicking on the image view; it doesn't come up, and after filling the other detail I can't create a new user due to the the imageview not being filled. I don't have no errors in my logcat.It only stopped creating a new user after implementing the Image part in the code.

```
package com.example.appdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText userName, userPassword, userEmail,userAge;
    private Button regButton;
    private TextView userLogin;
    private ImageView userProfilePic;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String email, name, age, password;
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    private static int PICK_IMAGE = 123;
    Uri imagePath;
    private StorageReference storageReference;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && requestCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null){
            imagePath = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),imagePath);
                userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
        setupUIViewas();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

         storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();


        userProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");// for document //application/* audio/* mp3/*
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select image"),PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(validate()){
                    //upload data to database
                    String user_email = userEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_password = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                       firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email,user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                //have to put the verification code here.
                                sendUserData();
                                // signs out user after registration and send you to login
                                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this,"Registration successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                            }else{                                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this,"Registration failed please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        userLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
    private void setupUIViewas(){
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserPassword);
        userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserEmail);
        regButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        userLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserLogin);
        userAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        userProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);

    }

    private Boolean validate(){
        Boolean result = false;

         name = userName.getText().toString();
         password = userPassword.getText().toString();
         email = userEmail.getText().toString();
         age = userAge.getText().toString();

        if(name.isEmpty()|| password.isEmpty()||email.isEmpty() || age.isEmpty() || imagePath == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void sendUserData(){
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myref = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        StorageReference imageReference = storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile Pic");//User Id/Images/profile_pic.jpg
        UploadTask uploadTask = imageReference.putFile(imagePath);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this,"File upload failed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this,"File upload successful!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(age,email,name);
        myref.setValue(userProfile);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the condition you wrote in `onActivityResult` :)

The second `requestCode` should be `resultCode`.

Change:

> (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && ***requestCode*** == RESULT_OK &&
>   data.getData() != null)

To:

(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && ***resultCode*** == RESULT_OK &&
data.getData() != null)

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't see that and does makes sense.